# Extracting words from inside sentence using regex in swift

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I want a regex to extract `Starboy` and `The Weekend / Daft Punk` out of string:

```
The Weeknd / Daft Punk - text=\"Starboy\" song_spot=\"M\" MediaBaseId=\"2238986\" itunesTrackId=\"0\" amgTrackId=\"-1\" amgArtistId=\"0\" TAID=\"744880\" TPID=\"43758958\" cartcutId=\"08
```

So far this is my attempt

```
do {  
    let input = "The Weeknd / Daft Punk - text=\"Starboy\" song_spot=\"M\" MediaBaseId=\"2238986\" itunesTrackId=\"0\" amgTrackId=\"-1\" amgArtistId=\"0\" TAID=\"744880\" TPID=\"43758958\" cartcutId=\"0893584001\""  
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "text=\"(.*)", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)  
    let matches = regex.matches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count))  

    if let match = matches.first {  
        let range = match.range(at:1)  
        if let swiftRange = Range(range, in: input) {  
            let name = input[swiftRange]  
            print(name)  
        }  
    }  
} catch {  
    print("Regex was bad!")  
}
```

But this gives me the entire string

```
Starboy" song_spot="M" MediaBaseId="2238986" itunesTrackId="0" amgTrackId="-1" amgArtistId="0" TAID="744880" TPID="43758958" cartcutId="0893584001"
```

Comment: You've spelled "Weekend" incorrectly

Comment: (Among other problems) you need the famous "minimal match" - google it up!  Enjoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to capture all text up to the sequence `- text=` followed by any word(s) between quote marks you can use this regex `".*(?=(text=\"[\\w\\s]+\"))"` and to capture any word(s) after the sequence `text="` you can use this regex `"(?<=text=\")([\\w\\s]+)"`. If you want to capture both ranges just use "|" between them as follow:

```
let string = """
The Weeknd / Daft Punk - text=\"Starboy\" song_spot=\"M\" MediaBaseId=\"2238986\" itunesTrackId=\"0\" amgTrackId=\"-1\" amgArtistId=\"0\" TAID=\"744880\" TPID=\"43758958\" cartcutId=\"08
"""
let pattern = ".*(?=( - text=\"[\\w\\s]+\"))|(?<=text=\")([\\w\\s]+)"

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count))
    for match in matches {
        if let range = Range(match.range, in: string) {
            let name = string[range]
            print(name)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Regex was bad!")
}
```

---

This will print

```
The Weeknd / Daft Punk
Starboy
```